# How do I process a large number of zipped files loaded in memory without having to write them to the disk?

Tags: c#

I have a number of a zipped files in a folder stored on a Samsung EVO 970 SSD. Each zip file is 2GB+(while compressed) with 200K+ text files contained within, each file being between 5 to 1.5MB, essentially a large number of small text files.

Rather than extract the zip file and process each text file individually to an SSD, I'm trying to load each zip file in memory in full at the start of the processing and then read each file like shown at the end here.

My (maybe naive ) thinking is that if I could figure out a way to hold the whole zip file contents in the ram and process the text contents without decompressing the zip contents to disk, I would see material boost in the processing performance.

Currently it is taking about 10millisec on average to process every single text file even with the approach taken below.

```
var myMS = new MemoryStream();
using(var file = File.OpenRead(zipFile))
{                   
    file.CopyTo(myMS);
   
    using(var zip = new ZipArchive(myMS, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
       
        foreach(var entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            using(var reader = new StreamReader(entry.Open(),Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();

              //do something with the file
```

My question is does this approach make sense ? Given that the total number of files, including all zip files is in the millions, I could be sat here for a week waiting for processing to finish.

Comment: Do you need to do this programmatically? My take is that running 7-zip on those zip files will be a number of times faster. You could use 7-zip programmatically too

Comment: Why load the whole file into memory? Let the OS deal with that, no need to wait for the loading to finish. You can always decompress in memory, no need to write the files to disk. If you process the data in a streaming manner, you're fine with just using the decompression stream directly; otherwise it might be worth copying to a MemoryStream or something, we can't really help you with what's going to work better. And of course... just test it. We can't do the benchmark, you can. Keep in mind that on e.g. Windows 10, if you have enough RAM, the whole file will be kept in RAM after first read.

Comment: Of those 10ms, what is the hot method?

Comment: *I'm trying to load each zip file in memory* - sounds like a disaster. ZIPs, AFAIAA, are streamable in the sense that you can start extracting files in order without having to know the entire file, so loading 2Gb of data into ram unnecessarily would be way down on my priority list. What do you "do with the file" ?

Comment: thanks for your comments. It looks like loading the whole zip file in memory isn't the way to go. I'll continue exploring other options to optimise the processing and might add an answer here later once I've managed to bring the time down to an acceptable level.

Comment: Maybe Ionic.zip.dll aka DotNetZip is worth a look. System.IO.Compression Zipping support seems very basic.
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/CSharp.htm